# How to do something class exists or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rather strange problem. I need to do some stuff according to if `CSS` class exists or not. My code looks like this:

```
jQuery('#first-tab').on('mouseover mouseout', 'button.button-add-new', function(e) {
    console.log(this.className);
    console.log(this.className.indexOf('disabled'));
    console.log(this.className.indexOf('disabled') > -1);

    if (this.className.indexOf('disabled') > -1) {
        console.log('tooltip');

        if (e.type == 'mouseover')
            jQuery(this).tooltip('show');
        else
            jQuery(this).tooltip('hide');
    }
});
```

By default, when `DOM` loads there is no `disable` class, so when I put mouse on button no tooltip occurs as it should be. The I push other button which add `disabled` class to `button.button-add-new`. Now tooltip toggle as it should be. The problem starts when I remove `disabled` class from `button.button-add-new` - tooltip still works though it should not work as `disabled` class is removed. Here is result from console

```
btn btn-default btn-sm sites-templates-button-add-new-site
-1
false
--------------
btn btn-default btn-sm sites-templates-button-add-new-site
-1
false
--------------
// class disabled added
--------------
btn btn-default btn-sm sites-templates-button-add-new-site disabled
59
true
tooltip
--------------
btn btn-default btn-sm sites-templates-button-add-new-site disabled
59
true
tooltip
--------------
// class disabled removed, but tooltip stil works
--------------
btn btn-default btn-sm sites-templates-button-add-new-site
-1
false
--------------
btn btn-default btn-sm sites-templates-button-add-new-site
-1
false
--------------
btn btn-default btn-sm sites-templates-button-add-new-site
-1
false
--------------
btn btn-default btn-sm sites-templates-button-add-new-site
-1
false
```

Comment: hey, did you try $(your_object).hasClass('class_name') ?

Comment: [jQuery API Reference: hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Comment: yes, tried, same problem

Comment: Could you setup a fiddle of this code? I don't think the problem here is the class checking.

Comment: Try to add an else clause like `if (this.className.indexOf('disabled') > -1) { ... } else { jQuery(this).tooltip('hide'); }`. My guess is that `jQuery(this).tooltip('show');` is installing the tooltip and then it behaves by it self.

Comment: @Prusse Nice one, only now began to think about it, because the tooltip was only for the last selected element

Comment: From a quick inspection of http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/ I don't think you are using it right.

Comment: @Prusse it is from twitter bootstrap. The main idea is to use tooltip on disabled element, but jQuery doesn’t fire any events on this so I improvise with css

Comment: Ok... I will recomend to check it's documentation to be sure =)

Comment: Got any luck solving your problem? If you did give some feedback, it is nice. If don't you should really try to setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) like Viktor suggested.

Comment: @Prusse i already told that you were right except that there was not jQuery UI, but bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

try using Jquery .hasClass()

```
if ($(this).hasClass("yourclass")) {

    //Do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check like this

```
if ($('.yourclass').length){
     //Do something
}
```